# Is it possible to filter a control that refers to a subform?

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter, controls, subform

This is the code I am referring to:

```
Dim ctl as Control
For Each ctl In Me.Form
  If ctl.ControlType = acSubform
    ctl.Filter = "[StartDate] <= [Date] and [EndDate] >= [Date]"
    ctl.FilterOn = True
  End If
Next ctl
```

Apparently this doesn't work (and it has nothing to do with the filter string being invalid). I am guessing that I cannot use the Filter method on a control object. But is there a way to get around this? Maybe create a SubForm variable and somehow assign it to the object the Control is referring to? Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense. You neither can nor would apply a filter on all controls.

This is what you may have in mind:

```
With Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form
    .Filter = "[StartDate] <= [Date] and [EndDate] >= [Date]"
    .FilterOn = True
End With
```

Then it would be:

```
Dim ctl as Control
For Each ctl In Me.Form
  If ctl.ControlType = acSubform
    ctl.Form.Filter = "[StartDate] <= [Date] and [EndDate] >= [Date]"
    ctl.Form.FilterOn = True
  End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that all controls I am trying to filter are subforms. I added an if statement in my original post. Your example would work, but I have about 40 subforms I am trying to filter so I would prefer to do this in a loop rather than have 40 "withs".

Comment: Then include property Form of the control - as shown.